# A hard integral

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, normal-distribution, gamma-function

Looking for a solution for an integral:
$$I(k)=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{(\log (u)-k)^2}{2 s^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } s \left(1+u\right)} \, du .$$
So far I tried substitutions and by parts to no avail.

Comment: If you had $u$ instead of $(1+u)$ in the denominator, the integrand would be the density of the lognormal distribution.

Comment: Similar to @mlc, written another way, if we say that $\phi(x|\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the density of a normal r.v. with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $$I(k) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\phi(\log(u)|k,s^2)}{(1+u)}du.$$

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I believe it is the snowball effect. If it happens to have a catchy title, it gets many views very quickly. If it gets many views very quickly and some actions, it remains at the top of the page. Since it is at the top of the page, and has a catchy title, it gets more views, etc.

Comment: Is $s$ a constant?

Comment: @RaghavChaturvedi yes, $s$ is a constant.

Comment: Did you try to differentiate it with respect to $k$ or $s$?

Comment: Where'd the integral come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The change of variable $v = \log u$ shows that you're trying to integrate the **logistic-normal integral**.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{v-k}{s}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi} s} \frac{1}{1+e^{-v}}~\mathrm{d}v$$

I doubt there is a closed form solution, and none seems known.

See http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.372.3781&rep=rep1&type=pdf for the approximation

$$\left|I(s,k)- \frac{1}{1+e^{-\frac{k}{\sqrt{1+\frac{\pi s^2}{8}}}}}\right| < 0.02$$

and
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042712002518 for a deeper discussion.

Comment: Hmmm. Good answer. Definitely shows that a closed form is unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start: $I(0) = \frac{1}{2}$

**Proof:**

$$I(0) = \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{(\log u)^2}{2s^2}\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi} s (1+u)} \rm{d}u$$

Put $\log u = x$

\begin{align}
I(0) &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{2s^2}\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi} s} \frac{e^x}{1+e^x} \rm{d}x \\
&= \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{2s^2}\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi} s}\rm{d}x -  \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{2s^2}\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi} s} \frac{1}{1+e^x} \rm{d}x
\end{align}

The first integral is $1$. Call the second integral $K$.
$$K=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{2s^2}\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi} s} \frac{1}{1+e^x} \rm{d}x$$

Flipping the range around $0$,
$$K=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{2s^2}\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi} s} \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} \rm{d}x$$

Now take the average of the two expressions,
\begin{align}
K &=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{2s^2}\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi} s} \left[\frac{1}{1+e^x}+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}\right] \rm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\exp\left[-\frac{x^2}{2s^2}\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi} s}\rm{d}x\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\\
I(0) &= 1 - K = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: The devil is for $k$ different from 0. This result is easily reached by expanding arounf $k$. Even Mathematica integrates to ½ for $k=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ is an integer multiple of $s^2$, then it appears you can use the result $I(0)=\frac12$ to obtain $I(k)$ as a sum of a finite number of terms.

Comment: But this doesn't really seem to answer the question...

Comment: Start with the logistic-normal shown in Arthur's answer.  Expand the 1/(1+e^(-v)) = 1 - e^(-v) + e^(-2v) - ...  .  Then integrate term by term (each one can be done in closed form).  You get an infinite series of terms.  But for k an integer multiple of s^2, you can sum the series for I(k).  It helps to know that the series for I(0) sums to 1/2.

Comment: So why isn't all the exposition in *your* answer? Answers should be complete!

Comment: Indeed, that sum is derived in the second link I posted. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042712002518